# Regex string insertion

Tags: python, regex, string, search, recompile

Simple, simple question, hope you can help me:

How do I add a string to a regex? 
Say:

```
d = '\d\d\d'
mo = re.compile(r #d goes here)
```

Pasting it, separating it with a comma, or with a plus gives me errors.
Normally, as you know, it would be re.compile(r'\d\d\d')

Comment: The `r` is just there to prevent certain escape sequences − you don't *need* it and can just type `re.compile(r)` or (perhaps better), `d = r'\d\d\d'` `re.compile(d)` ... Also [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2081640/660921).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
d = r"\d\d\d"
re.compile(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe more intuitive:

```
d = r"\d{3}"
# match a digit exactly three times, consecutively
re.compile(d)
```